# Website width jquery.scollto plugin doesn't work on all mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I'm working on a responsive website and use the [jquery.scrollTo plugin](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) for navigation. It works nice with desktop browsers and also on a samsung galaxy tab (with firefox and standard-android-browser). But on mobile (galaxy s III) there are problems with firefox and chrome. In both of them, the scroll-navigation is broken. With the demo-page of the plugin it works nice so I think it is an implementation problem.

Also in firefox the startpage has got a height of 200% where 100% is expected.

I hosted [the current version here](http://netzkratzen.de/tmp/).

Would be very glad if someone has an idea. I'm out of them so far :(

Thanks, Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your meta viewport by this :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

It's working on my xperia z3 [image]

Comment: Hey, it works great now! Thanks a lot. Think I should have a deeper look at that meta-tag.